# I'm trying to make a set role command and a set channel command. I've attempted to do it but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So what's going on is that I'm trying to make a set role/set channel command for logs and a mute role to mute people with and I'm wondering how to do this. I have looked at the docs and other stackoverflow threads and it still doesn't work.

```js
                if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a arg')
                let roleName = args.slice(2).join(" ");
                var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName)
                if(!role){
                    message.channel.send("Thats not a role!")
                }
                if(role){
                await GuildConfigSchema.update({ Guild: message.guild.id }, { MuteRole: role })
                message.channel.send(`The mute role is now ${role}`)
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it?  Is there an error, is it only executing part of it or none of it at all, etc.

Comment: It doesn't give a error it sends a message saying its not a role when I ping it and do it normally and adds the role to the database for some reason.

Comment: Try console.logging `roleName` to make sure it is what you're expecting it to be since you didn't show how you defined `args` in the code you gave.

Comment: If you are mentioning it, then wouldn’t that be <@&ROLEID>? You made it so you have to type the name of the role manually it seems

Comment: Anything, I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can use `if(role){ } else { }` something like that and second on comments you said ***when I ping it*** for your code ping will not work because you use `role.name` if you want to catch role with ping then use `let role = message.mentions.roles.first();`